# How to get all parameters from an Action type variable

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I need to build a trace that can log all parameters passed in a `Action` code variable.

How to get all parameters from the Action instance, considering that the action variable is filled with a lambda expression?

**Updated (clarifying the use of action object)**

I post below the API tracer that i am trying to build. The API tracer need to get parameters from lambda expressions passed in the action object:

```
public static class Tracer
{
    public static void log(Action action)
    {
      // note that action will always be set with a lambda function. See ServiceProxy class bellow.
      //..grab the action parameters and name and log them
    }
}
```

I only found ways to get these kind of information from expressions. From action type object, i don't find were it holds the parameters, only found the method name.

This Tracer is to use in a Proxy class that exposes an service. All calls should be logged. The Proxy uses an function wrapper that calls the service, like this:

```
class ServiceProxy:IServiceProxy {
   ...
   private void CallWrapper(Action func)
   {
        try
        {
            Tracer.log(func);
            func();
        }
        catch (Exception ex){...}
    }

    //method call example
    public void IServiceProxy.RequestX(String p1, int p2){
           CallWrapper(() =>  service.RequestX(p1, p2));//p1 and p2 parametersshould be logged by the Tracer.
    }       
}
```

In order to reuse the `CallWrapper` method, the lambda expression signature must be dynamic, this means `func` type can't be declared as an generic (ex:`Action<String,Int>`).

Comment: Which parameters? `Action` is delegate type for fuction without parameters.

Comment: IIRC there are no "parameters" you could get from a delegate (since it is basically just something "pointing to" a method, and doesn't really contain any more information like parameters etc). If you want more informations then you'll probably need to look into expression trees instead of working with delegates ([see MSDN for Expression Trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/)).

Comment: you can't get to them if you don't call it... perhaps you want to use an expression like `Tracer.log(() => func(...))`?

Comment: I added the RequestX method to show how it is used and what should be logged. Action object is a lambda function.

Comment: You need to change then CallWrapper to receive parameters as well, example private void CallWrapper<T>(Action<T> action, T arg)...CallWrapper<T1, T2>(Action<T1,T2> action, T1 arg1, T2 arg2) and so on...

Comment: But that way i can't reuse in other exposed methods that have different signatures.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. It a valid question in content and form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract your arguments with Linq.Expressions.
This mean you need to change `Action` to `Expression<Action>`.
Aftre doing that you will be capable to go through your lambda with custom expression visitor.

So lets start by adding a new class that would be inspect your expression:

```
public class ArgumentExtractor : System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> arguments;
    public IDictionary<string, object> Arguments => arguments;

    protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
    {
        arguments = node.Arguments
            .Select(a =>
            {
                var memeber = a as MemberExpression;
                if (memeber == null)
                    return null;

                var name = memeber.Member.Name;
                var container = (memeber.Expression as ConstantExpression)?.Value;
                var value = container.GetType().GetField(name).GetValue(container);

                return new {name, value};
            })
            .Where(x => x != null)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.name, x => x.value);

        return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
    }
}
```

Now we can use it in your `Tracer`:

```
public static class Tracer
{
    public static void log(Expression<Action> action)
    {
        var argumentExtractor = new ArgumentExtractor();
        argumentExtractor.Visit(action);

        var arguments = argumentExtractor.Arguments;
        // to do: write it to log
    }
}
```

Finaly we need to modify `CallWrapper`:

```
private static void CallWrapper(Expression<Action> func)
{
    Tracer.log(func);
    func.Compile().Invoke();
}
```

You can find full demo [here](https://gist.github.com/Aleks-Andreev/d57c5f25e9f58ec82de7a8a0d5e120a1)